# d3 force layout animations via web worker

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, canvas, web-worker

[image: lightbeam]

I have a d3 force layout graph. It can scale up to many nodes. Performance is the key here. The current implementation uses canvas element to render the graph while the force layout computations happen in web worker.

Anyone has thoughts how to achieve interactivity via web workers? Is it a good idea to spawn a thread for `mousedown` event and pass back the updated co-ordinates?

In short, how to achieve animations via web workers? Is it a good idea to involve workers for animating? Thanks in advance!